# How to retrieve XML with <![CDATA[...]]> using Jquery

Tags: jquery, xml, cdata

I'm having a minor issue with retrieving XML data with the CDATA string.

Here's my XML

```
<identifier rownumber="1">
<A.SOLUTION_ID>1001</A.SOLUTION_ID>
<A.LIBRARY_GROUP><![CDATA[Business Managment 1]]></A.LIBRARY_GROUP>
<A.LIBRARY_NAME><![CDATA[BM 01]]></A.LIBRARY_NAME>
</identifier>

<identifier rownumber="2">
<A.SOLUTION_ID>1002</A.SOLUTION_ID>
<A.LIBRARY_GROUP><![CDATA[Engineering]]></A.LIBRARY_GROUP>
<A.LIBRARY_NAME><![CDATA[ENG 05]]></A.LIBRARY_NAME>
</identifier>
```

My Jquery code

```
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: "http://myspace.com/external.xml",
dataType: "xml",
success: function parseXml(xml){
$(xml).find('identifier').each(function() {
    var rownumber = $(this).attr('rownumber');
    var A_LIBRARY_GROUP = $(this).find('A.LIBRARY_GROUP').text();

        $("#output").append("Row Number: " + rownumber + "<br/>");
        $("#output").append("A_LIBRARY_GROUP: " + A_LIBRARY_GROUP + "<br/><br/>-------------<br/>");
    });
```

Needed output:

```
Row Number: 1
A_LIBRARY_GROUP: Business Managment 1


Row Number: 2
A_LIBRARY_GROUP: Engineering
```

**My QUESTION: How can I retrieve the A.LIBRARY_GROUP and A.LIBRARY_NAME contents? It only shows a blank data. I can only retrieve the ROW NUMBER**

This is a retrieved external XML so the "." period character is included in the XML name.
Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Use $($.parseXML(xml))

Comment: Sorry not to add from my code above, I've used the parseXML already... $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://myspace.com/external.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function parseXml(xml){
 $(xml).find('identifier').each(function() {
 var rownumber = $(this).attr('rownumber');
 var A_LIBRARY_GROUP = $(this).find('A.LIBRARY_GROUP').text();
 
  $("#output").append("Row Number: " + rownumber + "<br/>");
  $("#output").append("A_LIBRARY_GROUP: " + A_LIBRARY_GROUP + "<br/><br/>-------------<br/>");
 });

Answer (score 0):

Example - [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Klors/mva7s/)

Your success function doesn't need a name and you shouldn't need to use `$.parseXML()`. If your ajax return type is already XML and the content is being transmitted using an XML MIME type, the AJAX call should already translate it into an XMLDoc.

Unfortunately it looks like jQuery doesn't really *do* XML, just HTML. You could use a hybrid of jQuery and native node traversal to get the values, or get an XML plugin.

For the hybrid, this should work...

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://myspace.com/external.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function (xml) {
        $(xml).find('identifier').each(function(i, o) {
            var rownumber = $(o).attr('rownumber');
            var A_LIBRARY_GROUP = o.getElementsByTagName('A.LIBRARY_GROUP')[0].textContent;

            $("#output").append("Row Number: " + rownumber + "<br/>");
            $("#output").append("A_LIBRARY_GROUP: " + A_LIBRARY_GROUP + "<br/><br/>-------------<br/>");
        });
    }
});
```

Also, just in case your XML example is your full XML, it's invalid without being contained in a single root element. Ie.

```
<somerootelement>
    <identifier rownumber="1">
        <A.SOLUTION_ID>1001</A.SOLUTION_ID>
        <A.LIBRARY_GROUP><![CDATA[Business Managment 1]]></A.LIBRARY_GROUP>
        <A.LIBRARY_NAME><![CDATA[BM 01]]></A.LIBRARY_NAME>
    </identifier>

    <identifier rownumber="2">
        <A.SOLUTION_ID>1002</A.SOLUTION_ID>
        <A.LIBRARY_GROUP><![CDATA[Engineering]]></A.LIBRARY_GROUP>
        <A.LIBRARY_NAME><![CDATA[ENG 05]]></A.LIBRARY_NAME>
    </identifier>
</somerootelement>
```

Comment: I tried this hybrid code, but it didn't work. It shows blank content. Any idea?

Comment: @syntaxcode Is your `external.xml` definitely being returned with a content type of `application/xml`?

Comment: @syntaxcode you could also try the `childNodes[0].data` instead of the `textContent` - I'll add a JsFiddle example to the answer

Comment: I can retrieve the <identifier rownumber="1">, etc... but when I add the rest of the CDATA contents ,then it shows blank. I can onle view the rownumber still.

Comment: @syntaxcode I've put an example in the answer, it uses a string with `$.parseXML()` but otherwise it should be the same as what you are trying to do

Comment: @syntaxcode Also, one thing with your example XML... is that the exact and complete XML that you are using? If so, it's invalid XML as you need a single root element surrounding the two `identifier` elements (the root element can be called anything, but there needs to just be one).

Comment: Here's the XML:
<?xml version='1.0'?>

<query numrows="2" queryname="DBSTANDARD_SOLUTIONS" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="">

<identifier rownumber="1">

<A.SOLUTION_ID>1001</A.SOLUTION_ID>

<A.LIBRARY_GROUP><![CDATA[Business Managment 1]]></A.LIBRARY_GROUP>

<A.LIBRARY_NAME><![CDATA[BM 01]]></A.LIBRARY_NAME>

</identifier>

<identifier rownumber="2">

<A.SOLUTION_ID>1002</A.SOLUTION_ID>

<A.LIBRARY_GROUP><![CDATA[Engineering]]></A.LIBRARY_GROUP>

<A.LIBRARY_NAME><![CDATA[ENG 05]]></A.LIBRARY_NAME>

</identifier>

</query>

Comment: @syntaxcode yes you've got a root element in there, `query`. That's fine. Are you sure the XML is being transmitted as `application/xml`? You can request the XML file directly in a browser and then use the network tab to view the headers of the response

Comment: I'm not sure why it's not displaying but I'll check on this further. I'll get back on this thread... Thanks!